# Dynamically add instances for routing from Ribbon client

Tags: java, spring-boot, ribbon

I am working on a spring boot module where i have a requirement to route my requests from a client side load balancer with discovery service enabled. I am using Ribbon client for this purpose , but for routing to multiple instances of the target endpoint i can see a property namely `server.ribbon.listOfServers` which contains a list of already created instances of the target. Is there a way i can dynamically create/ scale up the number of target instances with Ribbon ?